# Command-Option-R installs Sierra instead of Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, reinstall, macos-sierra, macos-mojave

I have a 15 inch 2017 MacBook Pro with the touchpad. From the documentation, `Command-Option-R` during startup should start a network install that installs the newest version of Mac OS compatible with my Mac.

However instead it always tries to install macOS Sierra. 
I understand that this was the old behavior before high Sierra, but this MacBook has been updated all the way to Mojave in the past so I expect the command to network install Mojave

I want to install Mojave directly, and I don’t have a usb-c flash drive. Do I have any other option besides installing Sierra and upgrading from the App Store?

Comment: It might be worth requesting to migrate this to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) - idk the answer, but others there might.

Comment: I'm looking through the menus but I cant find where I would request this.
Can you show me how?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to flag your own question for a moderator - I've never actually done it myself & don't have anything I can test on, sorry.